# How do I get the next page of data from a instagram tag look up

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram, instagram-api

I can enter the following url to get all the IG posts with the #losangeles tag in them by going/requesting the following endpoint:

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/losangeles/?__a=1
```

In the json data returned from this url i can see the page_info attribute and within it there is the has_next_page attribute and that is set equal to true. My question is how do I ammend the above url to get to the next page, and the one after that, and so until I check has_next_page and it is false.

It seemed intuitive to try

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/losangeles/?__a=2
```

and

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/losangeles/?__b=1
```

But neither seem to work. I suspect maybe the end_cursor attribute in the data returned from the original url may be a clue as to what url I need to go to to get to the next page but am not sure. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible. Each response includes an `end_cursor` parameter. In your next request add a `max_id` parameter using the value of `end_cursor`, like so: `https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/losangeles/?__a=1&max_id=<value>`.

I have a working example here written in react/axios: https://codepen.io/ghostreef/pen/ZrKrXX. My example pulls from a user account, so my response xml is different. The end_cursor for tags is at `data.graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.page_info.end_cursor` and the image data is at `data.graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges` and you'll have to iterate over the nodes.

Comment: Great, thank you! I use the call https://www.instagram.com/<accountname>/?__a=1&max_id=<value>, it only seems that some messages are missing. When you use this option. There is a gap of two messages between first en second call.

Comment: No longer works as you mentioned. Is there any other method now?

Comment: Just found a way!

Comment: @AndréYuhai Could you please share your solution here?

Comment: @killernova I'd explained it in my answer below. Take a look at it please if you haven't seen.

Comment: great solution man! is there any way to set the number of items to retrieve? I tries `&count=100` for example, but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Well I've just read [this article](https://www.diggernaut.com/blog/how-to-scrape-pages-infinite-scroll-extracting-data-from-instagram/#comment-215) and applied the same procedure on the tag page and you can definitely do  this on any other page you would like.

You can inspect every request (and also JavaScripts) on the browser to find where `query_hash` and `after`parameters come from.

## What is the requested URL when we load more content?

First of all, let's  take a look at what is the requested URL when we load more content. You can simply do this by going to https://instagram.com/explore/tags/ruby and then scroll down until it loads another chunk of images while inspecting.

You will see a `GET` request to below URL:

[https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=1780c1b186e2c37de9f7da95ce41bb67&variables={"tag_name":"ruby","first":12,"after":"AQAFSpwCDXVgp2pnTXf57MavtlZnwU4ptNnC6nRGtIs5C9erOWwzZkcfSiq812RlMqDLzKlCzsAx-b9sIsIm4X4REE1LbZeA5yok7yA2jGcJqg"}](https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=1780c1b186e2c37de9f7da95ce41bb67&variables=%7B%22tag_name%22:%22ruby%22,%22first%22:12,%22after%22:%22AQAFSpwCDXVgp2pnTXf57MavtlZnwU4ptNnC6nRGtIs5C9erOWwzZkcfSiq812RlMqDLzKlCzsAx-b9sIsIm4X4REE1LbZeA5yok7yA2jGcJqg%22%7D)

## What do we need to know to get the next page?

Well as you see above in the link we need:

1. `query_hash`
2. `after`

I couldn't really figure out how `first` parameter works but it loads more content if you put a greater value but not exactly the same number of content.

## Where do we get variables `after` and `query_hash`?

So far so good. If we know the `query_hash` and `after` variables we can request the next page of the images.

You can easily get to a tag page's first JSON file by the help of this link:

`https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/yourtagname/?__a=1`

I've used `ruby` tag so mine would be:

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/ruby/?__a=1

After loading the JSON file you can see there is a variable called `end_cursor`. This is our `after` parameter.

[image: end_cursor variable preview]

---

To get your `query_hash` parameter you will need to take a look at the `.js` file

https://www.instagram.com/static/bundles/base/TagPageContainer.js/f1172b0dfea6.js

Then there you just need to search for the string `byTagName.get(t).pagination},queryId:"` which is followed by the `query_hash` you will need.

Then just put all the pieces together using the variables we've found above and browse to our new link to get the JSON file of the next page like so.

[https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=1780c1b186e2c37de9f7da95ce41bb67&variables={"tag_name":"ruby","first":9,"after":"AQDPE3V-ycMcCFjHv8Gq7MnR-x2hxNOI6WQGO8psxHsRWJo3pIDpR-qaKUITQGE3-dvEYYdG4ueWzSPLabVH7VOBZq4oWZYvsjswh2w622HwEQ"}](https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=1780c1b186e2c37de9f7da95ce41bb67&variables=%7B"tag_name":"ruby","first":9,"after":"AQDPE3V-ycMcCFjHv8Gq7MnR-x2hxNOI6WQGO8psxHsRWJo3pIDpR-qaKUITQGE3-dvEYYdG4ueWzSPLabVH7VOBZq4oWZYvsjswh2w622HwEQ"%7D)

Comment: If someone need profile data, the query_hash can be found inside 
ProfilePageContainer file i.e. https://www.instagram.com/static/bundles/es6/ProfilePageContainer.js/38a6b4cf0614.js.

Comment: Can anybody help me how to access this queryId value programatically. Its not a good idea to parse whole JS file every-time you send a new profile request.

Answer (score 2):

April 2021 update - Yesterday, Instagram changed the response with tags lookup. As a result, if you look for a specific tag, the response will not contain an "end_cursor" anymore. Instead, you should look for an element called "next_max_id" (located at the very bottom of the response you get from Instagram). The value is similar: eg: QVFBUTVDc2xKMnRKSVZseVdFNk5wR05zRkt4ODhUUWg2dzU2VlVhMUxGZ2xobVc4V01Jby1TM1pRRmFaWUIxRmJkUmdDSjVOc24wVDlOc0NiQTB2Z3U3Vg==

Comment: is there any way to set the number of items to retrieve? I tries &count=100 for example, but didn't work.